# Low Seg to cat (if category not found)

Tags: low, low-seg2cat

If the seg_to_cat can't be analyzed, (the category doesn't exist), the resulting page shows all the entries in the channel. What can be done to show instead a "no results found" page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally check your segment variables from the extension:

```
{if segment_2_category_name}

    This category exists.

    {exp:channel:entries category="{segment_2_category_id}"}
        ...{title}...
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{if:else}

    No results code, or {redirect="404"}

{/if}
```